# Remove div created by script from DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have a third-party script that creates a `div` in the DOM.

The script is this one:

```
        const s1 = document.createElement('script');
        const s0 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s1.async = true;
        s1.src = getWidget();
        s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
        s1.id = 'TAWK';
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
```

This script creates a `div` with dynamic `id` and no `class`.

I need to remove this `div` entirely and recreate it whenever a user clicks on a button in my website. This is because `s1.src` is dynamic as well, so I need to change the `src` of the script.

How can I get the `div` created by this script and remove it?

Thanks in advance

Edit: here is the script https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/77XFNJQZrj/

Comment: What is there in the script creating the div?

Comment: It's a huge script that renders a chat. The problem is that I need to change the script src based on the language that user is viewing. So, whenever the user changes the language of the website, I need to delete the div and redownload the new one from another src

Comment: But we need to see the script creating the div, in order to get a clue where it is placed and how it can be identified. Seeing a script creating a script tag is not useful when solving your problem. You've to isolate the part which creates the div, and post that code.

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/77XFNJQZrj/

Comment: I'm afraid you've to help yourself with this. Open the DevTool at Inspector tab, and activate the div to be removed. Then you can see where it is placed in the document tree, and possible identifiers (like an id, a class name etc.) Then you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (possibly combined with child/sibling getters) to get a reference to the element, removing it should be trivial ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand where it is in DOM and get it by the selector

1.) Open the inspector in the browser and see where your div was generated, example:

[image]

2.) Then look where it is, next to which element or in which container

most likely your element is generated by the last element in the document body

Read about [querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) on how to get a selector

And for example, if your element is the last in the body of the document:

```
document.body.lastElementChild.remove();
```

Attention! This is completely unsafe, it is better to do an additional check on the tag name or regex:

```
let getMyDiv = (children) => {
    for(let i = children.length; i > 0; i--) {
        let el = children[i-1];
        // Search by tag and if the class starts with .. 
        if(el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div' && /^box/.test(el.className)) {
            return el
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let children = document.body.children;
    console.log(getMyDiv(children));
});
```